# I have an unstable internet connection

Tags: internet

Every time I get connected to the internet, no matter what, after some minutes, I get

disconnected. My connection including my ISP and MODEM and everything is all-alright

because when I go to my windows 7 operating system everything works perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using wireless? If you are:

1. See if you can get a better connection with WICD.
2. Hidden SSIDs and hardware access lists are still problematic, as well as WPA
3. Try proprietary Broadcom drivers from Synaptic>Repositories>Additional Drivers
4. Use ndiswrapper and a windows driver

Comment: How do you know that those drivers you mentioned will help him? He didn't say anything about his hardware, did he?